Why is there a stark difference in behaviour of the Llama 1B model when running is locally using Ollama and online using the HuggingFace Inference?
I'm running an experiment where I need to calculate the BLEU and ROUGE scores of the Llama 1B model running locally on my phone using executorch. For the benchmark texts, I need the outputs generated by Llama 1B on my laptop. However, I'm confused as for what to use because of the stark difference in outputs.
When running the same model using Ollama, the model works really well for both general text generation and question answering prompts. But when running inference using the HuggingFace inference API, the model seems to hallucinate a lot. It works fine for general sentence completion like "Once upon a time..." but works terribly for and question-based prompt like "Are property and house tax the same?". The picture (https://i.sstatic.net/2feV5RbM.png) of shows the responses for Ollama and the responses from HuggingFace is something like -
is house tax and property tax are same?\nQ: is house tax and property tax are same?
\nWhat is the difference between house tax and property tax?\nHouse tax is the amount 
that is paid to the local government by the owner of the property. Property tax is the
 amount that is paid to the local government by the owner of the property.\nWhat is the 
difference between house tax and property tax?\nHouse tax is the amount that is paid to
 the local government by the owner of the property. Property tax is the amount that is 
paid to the local government by the owner of the property.\nWhat`

A behaviour similar to the HuggingFace inference is also seen on the model running locally on my phone via executorch. Any reason why, and how can I correct this?
I ran the model on my mobile just as described in the executorch repository.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
